# Autocompleting list of choices with 'other' option in django

Tags: jquery, python, django, autocomplete, django-forms

I have a django form element (Musical Instrument) where I'd like to autocomplete from a list of choices (e.g. ['Piano', 'Guitar', 'Drums', 'Bass']), but allow the user to enter something else if it isn't in the list.

I'm currently using autocomplete-light, but can swap this for something else if need be.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the model and form.

If you are using a simple charfield in your model and set the choices in the automcomplete class, you should be able to input arbitrary values.